# Getting top values from a list in c sharp

Tags: c#, list, loops

So I'm having some trouble with a C# program that is meant to sum the 8 highness value from a list.

The program works by declaring a variable `currenthigh`, which stores a value from the `gradelist`. It then compares itself to the value `abshigh` to see if it is greater than the established highest value. If it is, it sets `currenthigh` as the new highest value.

Once the loop has run through the list and confirmed the highest value, it adds it to the `uppertotal` variable and uses the `ejector` variable to remove it from the list. The program then iterates, this time without the previous highest value. It iterates 8 times so that in the end the top 8 values are added to `uppertotal`.

Trouble is, the highest variable remains in the list, despite the code having instructions to delete it, so it just adds the highest value to itself 8 times.

```
int currenthigh = 0;
int abshigh = 0;
int ejector = 0;
int uppertotal = 0;

for (int g = 0; g < 8; g++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < gradelist.Count; z++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PASS STARTED");
        currenthigh = Convert.ToInt32((gradelist[z]));
        Console.WriteLine("currenthigh" + currenthigh);

        if (currenthigh > abshigh)
        {
            abshigh = currenthigh;
            ejector = z;
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("ejector" + ejector);
    uppertotal = uppertotal + currenthigh;

    gradelist.RemoveAt(ejector);
    Console.WriteLine("PASS COMPLETE");
    Console.WriteLine("RESETING");      
}
```

*Note - `gradelist` is a list of integers containing at least 12 items at all time.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you do not remove the highest value from gradelist. Pay attention, you put Z in ejector, but Z is an index in gradelist and when you try to remove it, you remove nothing because there is no Z in gradelist as a member! Instead of

```
gradelist.RemoveAt(ejector);
```

you should do this:

```
gradelist.RemoveAt(gradelist[ejector]);
```

But I'd recommend you completely different approach. If you just want to get your uppertotal which is the sum of top 8 members in gradlist, use this simple trick:

```
uppertotal += gradelist.OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(8).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is extremely big for the relatively simple task.
You can select the top `X` of a list as follows:

```
top_list = gradelist.OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(X)
```

When working with lists/collections `System.Linq` is your friend

Comment: Both true, I'm currently not behind a pc with VS so can't proof-run it :). Thanks for the fb, the code should be runnable now

Comment: Thank yo! I was not aware of this method!